# No Sound is playing

Tags: iphone, ios4, memory, audio

```
-(IBAction)test1
{
    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();

    CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
    soundFileURLRef =CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, 
                                             (CFStringRef) @"Bear3", CFSTR ("wav"), NULL);

    UInt32 soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef , &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
    AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(soundID);
    CFRelease(soundFileURLRef);
}
```

It is not playing the sound file

Comment: Are you getting an error?  What *is* happening?

Answer (score 3):

Your code is not working because you dispose of your resources before you are done with them.

```
AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(soundID);
```

Should not be called while you are playing the sound. You need to reorganize your code.

You should also avoid the `CF` classes if higher-level `NS` classes can do the job. And in this case they can. Here's how:

Code in response to comment:
SoundExampleViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
@interface SoundExampleViewController : UIViewController{
    SystemSoundID bear3SoundID;
}
-(IBAction)playSoundButtonPushed:(id)sender;
@end
```

SoundExampleViewController.m:

```
#import "SoundExampleViewController.h"
@implementation SoundExampleViewController
-(IBAction)playSoundButtonPushed:(id)sender{
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(bear3SoundID);
}
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Bear3" ofType:@"wav"]; 
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path],&bear3SoundID);
}
- (void)viewDidUnload{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(bear3SoundID);
}
@end
```

Even if you stick with the `CF` classes in the `viewDidLoad` method, you should follow this general layout.

Comment: is that the new code i have to add. i just started programming so i don't know much

Comment: will that code work to make a soundboard app do i just copy that code for each sound

Comment: Yes this code will work for a soundboard app. For multiple sounds just create more soundIDs in the same way. Of course each sound would likely have it's own IBAction method.